# Как отслеживать движение игрока в определённом направлении в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу чтобы при движении в определённом направлении мой персонаж поворачивался в ту же сторону. Как мне отследить движение игрока в определённом направлении?

Например: вперёд, назад, влево, вправо.

игра в 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Нахождение угла по двум осям (`x`, `z` в данном случае):

```
float Rad = Mathf.Atan2(velocity.x, velocity.z); // в радианах
float Ang = Rad/Mathf.PI*180f; // в градусах
```