# Как отслеживать движение персонажа в определённую сторону в опеределённом направлении в GetAxis в unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу чтобы мой персонаж поворачивался в ту сторону, в которую он идёт.

Сам поворот я уже сделал. Мне нужно отследить поворот в определённую сторону в `Input.GetAxis` в `Unity3D`.

Возможно ли это? Если нет, то как тогда мне это сделать? Игра в 3D если что.

Comment: Зарегистрировал второй аккаунт, чтобы задать тот-же вопрос... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097227/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-unity3d